# How to invoke a listener from another listener?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using [`in_app_purchase`](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package and I need to convert/map listener which is listening for `List<PurchaseDetails>` to another listener as shown below:

```dart
class Foo {
  Foo() {
    InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream.listen(_listener);
  }

  void _listener(List<PurchaseDetails> list) {
    // How to pass these ids to `addListener()`
    final List<String> ids = list.map((e) => e.productID).toList();
  }

  void addListener(void Function(List<String>) f) {}
}
```

This is how I want to use my listener

```dart
void main() {
  Foo().addListener((List<String> ids) {});
}
```

Comment: "`Foo` which has an `int` listener." This doesn't make sense.  A listener is something that waits for events, usually something that is notified when an object changes. `int`s are immutable. `_listener`, despite its name, does not seem to be listening to anything.  How is `_listener` supposed to be called?  Can you provide a more complete example of what you want?

Comment: @jamesdlin I have provided full example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what your code comment says, I think what you're really asking for is for the internal `_listener` to invoke the *callback* that was previously passed as an argument to `addListener` (and not for `_listener` to call `addListener` directly, which it could just do directly).

Just have `addListener` save the callback to a member variable and let your internal listener invoke that:

```dart
class Foo {
  void Function(List<String>)? _listener;
  
  Foo() {
    InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream.listen(_internalListener);
  }

  void _internalListener(List<PurchaseDetails> list) {
    var listener = _listener;
    if (listener == null) {
      return;
    }

    final List<String> ids = list.map((e) => e.productID).toList();
    listener(ids);
  }

  void addListener(void Function(List<String>) f) => _listener = f;
}
```

If you want callers to be able to call `addListener` multiple times to register multiple callbacks, you would need to store them in a collection (and provide a mechanism to unregister callbacks):

```dart
class Foo {
  final _listenerMap = <Object, void Function(List<String>)>{};
  
  Foo() {
    InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream.listen(_internalListener);
  }

  void _internalListener(List<PurchaseDetails> list) {
    if (_listenerMap.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    final List<String> ids = list.map((e) => e.productID).toList();
    for (var listener in _listenerMap.values) {
      listener(ids);
    }
  }

  Object addListener(void Function(List<String>) f) {
    var token = Object();
    _listenerMap[token] = f;
    return token;
  }
  
  void removeListener(Object token) {
    _listenerMap.remove(token);
  }
}
```